# Redmine API - USER - POST Creates a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http-post, redmine, redmine-api

```
http://demo.redmine.org/account/register
http://demo.redmine.org/users.xml
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Users#POST
```

I tried to create a user using the http method post as the Redmine wiki page suggest. it's not working. The page was /users.xml and /users.Json. I use Postman which is an app for Google chrome browser. I used it to check if there is a "POST" method for the request but it's said there is no "POST" and there is only "GET" method that will get all users.

What should I do? I am building an iOS app for redmine and I want my users to have the ability to register from the app.
OR if I want to add the "post" method to the api how can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Redmine .NET API library for C# as they suggest [here](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_csharp). It provides access and basic CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete) for redmine resources.